# How could we prove that it is not a spanning set.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, transcendental-numbers

Consider the space $\mathbb{R}$ as a linear space over the field  $\mathbb{Q}$ of rational numbers.  For any transcendental number *x* the set {*1, $x$, $x^2$, $x^3$,......*} is linearly independent. How could we prove that it is not a spanning set.

Comment: Spanning set for what? $\Bbb R$?

Answer (score 2):

I imagine that you mean linearly independant over $\mathbb {Q}$. It is important to precise the field. Then you can invoke a cardinality argument, i.e. the cardinal of the span subspace of your set over $\mathbb {Q}$ is countable, while the set of real numbers is not.

Comment: @CameronWilliams: Huh? $0=0x$ does not say that $x$ is algebraic. Nor does $1=1.x^0$ if you meant to say $1$.